# When should you convert Age column in float or int?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I had this doubt, often datasets have the Age column values in either int or float datatype (Eg Titanic).
So suppose the column has all float values, should you convert them all to int or let it be just like that while feeding it to ML Model,
Does it have any harm or adverse effects in prediction results and what's the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`age` is a continuous variable**: every moment that passes you age, you don't age incrementally once a year, so the data type which most closely reflects reality is a `float` and not an `integer`. **However using a `float` or an `integer` depends on the use case**, eg:

- Are you using `age` as a **feature describing how old people are**? Better use **float** (eg a person who is 59.9 is older than a person who is 59.1 and may be more likely to develop certain medical conditions, or maybe less physically fit and less likely to survive in an event of a sinking ship)
- Are you reporting on `age` **groups**? Might be better off **rounding to nearest integer** (eg 39.9 -> 40, 34.2 -> 34) and potentially **binning** (eg 25-34, 35-45)
- Are you looking at age from a **legal standpoint**? (e.g. analysis of underage drinking) then you should use the **rounded down** `int` value (eg if legal age is 16 and a person is 15.9, legally they are 15 and therefore underage drinking)
- etc...

As a general remark you'll often find that there is no single `"right way"` of dealing with data, it all depends on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to convert the **age** column in to int. If some junk values would come, it would impact the model. We both knows quite well that age is an integer.

If data quality is superior and you are sure that age wont come in float then you can proceed without conversion too.